# Python, opening the file, reading the file, editing the file, and priting the file string?

Tags: python

So i am suppose to open a text file by >>>yyy('yyy.txt') and after inputing that python should find my file (which is does, since in the same directory) and edit all the words 'hot' to new word 'why not'. after editing the text file the content of the entire file should be printed.

Its opening the file and its editing 'hot' with 'why not' but it duplicates the whole text in the text file and it does not return anything on the python when i need the text to be displayed.

Any help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.write()` appends to the end of the file. You never clear the file after reading the contents. The simplest thing to do, probably, would be to read the file once in 'r' mode, then open it again in 'w' mode (which will clear the file), and write out the edited content.

The output doesn't print because you don't tell it to. Calling `infile.readlines()` on its own just reads the file, then discards the result. The final line should be `print infile.readlines()`.

Comment: Yes, as I just said, opening in 'w' mode clears the file -- which you'll have to do if you want to overwrite what's already there. Open it in 'r' mode _and read the contents_, then open in 'w' mode.

Comment: f1 is just a handle to the file on disk. The file's contents are not stored in memory until you _read_ them in some way -- in this case through `for line in f1`. Calling open('yyy.txt', 'w') erases the file's entire contents _immediately_, as soon as it is called -- which in your case is BEFORE you've read anything out of the file. Open the file in 'r', _read the contents_ to a variable in memory (opening the file is distinct from reading the contents), _then_ you can safely truncate the file.

Comment: if you call `contents = f1.readlines()` before opening f2, then yes, `contents` should now contain the contents of the file.

I'm sure this is obvious, but you did replace the file after it was cleared, correct?

Comment: nm naming issue duh. i knew it was something stupid. for line in content.......f2.write. Its working now. Thank you sir for all your help you are a scholar.